# Cannot delete windows files

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I cannot delete a file that has security as following picture.
I am using windows 10. Anyone has any idea about this?

[image]

Comment: It is possible to modify permissions for a folder higher in the tree and then push it down, overriding the permissions. But it may break other files. You can also try if you can make yourself owner of the file, then you can change the permissions too. Have you tried any of these?

Comment: You don’t own the file.  So you have no permissions. You cannot even read the file in order to view it’s permissions. You need to take ownership of the file or as the owner of the file grant the user profile in question permissions to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a game, where a desktop icon was installed in administrator
mode and requires administrator permissions to delete.

The best solution will be to uninstall the game in question.

If you only wish to delete the icon and leave the game,
[run File Explorer as Administrator](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/13933-how-run-file-explorer-administrator.html),
position to the folder and delete the icon.